# How to make PayPalCheckout return value by post method?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, checkout

I am using [PayPalCheckoutSdk](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK) library following the examples, I have the following:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/PayPalCheckout/vendor/autoload.php';

    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;

    $clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    $environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    $client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);

    $invoiceNumber = uniqid();
    
    $items = array();

    $items[0] = [
        'name' => 'HTML5',
        'description' => 'Video streaming service',
        'type' => 'SERVICE',
        'sku' => 'sku03',
        'unit_amount' =>
            [
                'currency_code' => 'USD',
                'value' => '90.00',
            ],
        'quantity' => '1',
        'category' => 'DIGITAL_GOODS',
    ];
    $new_item = [
        'name' => 'CSS3',
        'description' => 'Video streaming service',
        'type' => 'SERVICE',
        'sku' => 'sku02',
        'unit_amount' =>
            [
                'currency_code' => 'USD',
                'value' => '45.00',
            ],
        'quantity' => '2',
        'category' => 'DIGITAL_GOODS',
    ];

    array_push($items , $new_item);

    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();

    $request->prefer('return=representation');

    $request->body = [
        'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
        'application_context' => [
            'brand_name' => 'COMPANY',
            'locale' => 'us-US',
            'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW',
            "cancel_url" => "http://localhost/PayPal/cancel.php",
            "return_url" => "http://localhost/PayPal/return.php",
            'landing_page' => 'BILLING',
        ],
        'purchase_units' => [0 => [
            'reference_id' => $invoiceNumber,
            'amount' => [
                'currency_code' => 'USD',
                'value' => '160.00',
                'breakdown' => [
                    'item_total' => [
                        'currency_code' => 'USD',
                        'value' => '180.00',
                    ],
                    'shipping_discount' => [
                        'currency_code' => 'USD',
                        'value' => '20.00',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'items' =>
                $items,
        ]],
    ];

    try {
        $response= $client->execute($request);

        if ($response->statusCode == 201){
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($response->result->links); ++$i){
                $link = $response->result->links[$i];
                if ($link->rel =='approve') {
                    header("location: $link->href");
                }
            }
        } else {
            exit(1);
        }
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
        echo $ex->statusCode;
        print_r($ex->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

I am receiving the data by get method `print_r($_REQUEST);`:

```
Array ( [token] => 3JX899952R0552721 [PayerID] => J95XSJRX4WXVS
```

And, that information is processed in the file `return.php` which has the following code: https://ideone.com/ncVjIt

I would like to be able to receive the information but by post method, what configurations should I make so that the data is sent by post and not by get?

Comment: You can’t. After paying on the paypal site, the user is redirected back to the specified `return_url` in their own browser. That redirect means GET request, there is no way for you to turn that into a POST.

Comment: @CBroe I thought it was possible, in your examples three links were observed (self, approve, capture) two from the get method and the last one from the post method.

Comment: _“in your examples three links were observed (self, approve, capture)”_ - I don’t know what you are talking about there. // A POST request made from the payment gateway to your _server_ is usually an option these gateways provide (“webhook”), but that would happen in the background.

Comment: @CBroe I mean the output data examples that are in the documentation on Github. Ok, I understand, apparently everything does differently when done with forms if it receives data by post method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments, you can't change the redirect method back from PayPal. It will always be a GET string appended to your `return_url`.

However, the ideal and recommended solution is to not use any redirects. At all. Instead, use the PayPal-Checkout-SDK you have to make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls), that return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair these two JSON-only routes with the following approval flow that does not use any redirects, and instead keeps your site loaded in the background (lightboxed) at all times during payment approval: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server